# How can I list the contents of a directory of a webdav server with wildcards?

Tags: webdav

Is it possible with DAV:like in a propfind-xml-document?

```
<D:where>
  <D:like>
    <D:prop><D:getfilename/></D:prop>
    <D:literal>mypic_thumb%.jpg</D:literal>
  </D:like>
</D:where>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the filename is not a WebDAV property.

Comment: Is there any other possibility to filter list results (for example with header statements).

Comment: No, at least not in standards space.